# Entity Framework separate initialization context and info models

Tags: entity-framework, domain-driven-design, entity-framework-6

I am trying to set up multiple `DbContext` objects in my solution. One will be the initialization context and the others will be bounded contexts.

The scenario I am having difficulty resolving is as follows:

Having two database tables, a parent object and a child object. Upon initialization the tables are created okay with all the properties on, however in the bounded context I want to use the parent object and only return a subset of properties from the child object.

At the moment both the initialization context and the bounded context use the same parent class so therefore I can't use a third info object for the child object in the bounded context.

Would I therefore need to create another parent object for use in the bounded context which uses another child object with subset of properties?

So would I need in the initialization context a parent and child object and in the bounded context a separate parent and child object where the child object only has a subset of properties and the parent object points to that child?

I am quite happy to create the child class with a subset of properties but it seems a bit long winded to create a separate parent object to point to the child info object but I can't see a way around this.

Answer (score 0):

Having watched Julie Lermans TechEd Europe 2014 "Entity Framework Model Partitioning in Domain-Driven Design Bounded Contexts" https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rGA_FNew-6g I have decided to go down the route of having a master context purely for database migrations.

I found the idea of using events and message queues and separating the data into different tables in the database interesting but it's probably a bit heavy handed for our needs at the moment.